# Embed radio buttons in multi select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way (using html/jquery) I can embed radio buttons in the options of a multi select list?

ex:

`<select multiple>

  <option>USA

    <input type="radio" name="subregion" value="dma">DMA

    <input type="radio" name="subregion" value="states">States

  </option>

  <option>Canada

    <input type="radio" name="subregion" value="dma">DMA

    <input type="radio" name="subregion" value="provinces">Provinces

  </option>

  ...

  ...

  ...

  ...

</select>`

Comment: You cannot do this with `<select>` tags...you would need to create a custom select box using `<div>` and other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot nest other HTML elements in a SELECT. If this is the functionality you really need, consider a DIV-based drop-down replacement.